# angular injector error Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Please Help me,

I have a controller like this :

showAlert below was triggered from a button with ng-click=showAlert(data.nip)

```
var showAlert = function ($scope, $modal, $log, nip) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'public/js/modal.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            nip: function () {
                return nip;
            }
        }
    });
}
showAlert.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'nip'];

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, nip) {
    $scope.nip = nip;
    console.log("Nilai NIP : "+nip)
};
```

from state :

```
.state('masterpegawai.alltalenta.modal', {
        url: '/modal',
        views:{
          "modal": {
            controller: showAlert,
          }
        }
     })
```

It throws error like this :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nipProvider <- nip
```

Comment: Apparently you haven't included a file with `nip` module and you didn't bothered to search your error as there is probably hundreds  of these errors floating around

Comment: Hi maurycy, I am new to angular, actually I tend to pass data.nip from showAlert(data.nip) so that it can be shown in modal dialog through  resolve: {
            nip: function () {
                return nip;
            }
        }

Comment: the `nip` is not existing, it has to be defined as service, factory or directive then you can inject it. It is an equivalent of calling a function that wasn't defined yet

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to inject `nip`, but from your code you're trying to pass it with as a parameter:

```
showAlert.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'nip']; <-- You can't inject  'nip'
```

Comment: So how to pass data.nip from showAlert(data.nip) so that it can be delivered to resolve ?

Comment: I would separate the controller from the function that opens the modal, and inject the modal and just pass the parameter to the function